# Splint static analyser: not finding splint.rc configuration file (Windows)

Tags: c, windows, cmd, splint

According the [Splint FAQ](http://www.splint.org/faq.html):

> For Win32, Splint looks for splint.rc instead of .splintrc due to the
>   DOS filename limitations. It will look first in the current directory,
>   then in your home directory.

I've set up a very simple test to try to get Splint working:

- step 1: Extract `splint-3.1.1.win32.zip` into `c:\splint`
- step 2: In `c:\test\test.c` put a simple program:

  void main(void){
  }
- step 3: Run "cmd"
- step 4: Enter command: `cd c:\test\`

***Then I try to use splint, without splint.rc, and no flags***

- step 5: Enter command `c:\splint\bin\splint.exe test.c'

As expected, this produces the output `The function main does not output the expected type`

***Then I try to use splint, without splint.rc, and the -maintype flag***

- step 5: Enter command `c:\splint\bin\splint.exe test.c -maintype'

As expected, the output no longer produces `The function main does not output the expected type`.

***Then I try to use splint, with splint.rc, within which is the -maintype flag***

- step 5: in `c:\test\splint.rc` I put the contents `-maintype`.
- step 5: Enter command `c:\splint\bin\splint.exe test.c'

Because I entered `-maintype` in `splint.rc`, and because I'm running the splint command from the directory which has `splint.rc` in it, splint should not be coming up with the warning about the main function, but it does. I'm guessing splint is not picking up the splint.rc configuration file.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I have got it working by using the -f flag to include it:

```
c:\splint\bin\splint.exe test.c -f splint.rc
```